# In C++ when can one return a class instance?

Tags: c++

I am reading a [Java to C++ crash course](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs123/docs/java_to_cpp.shtml), beside others it talks about memory management in C++. An example is given to show what must not be done:

```
Foo& FooFactory::createBadFoo(int a, int b)
{
    Foo aLocalFooInstance(a, b);  // creates a local instance of the class Foo
    return aLocalFooInstance;     // returns a reference to this instance
}
```

This would not work because `aLocalFooInstance` leaves scope and is destroyed. Fine, makes sense to me. Now as one solution to this problem the following code is given:

```
Foo FooFactory::createFoo(int a, int b) 
{
    return Foo(a, b);  // returns an instance of Foo
}
```

What I don't understand: why is the second example valid C++ code? Is the basic issue not the same in both examples, that is, that an instance of `Foo` is created, which would go out of scope and is thus destroyed when we return from the method?

Comment: The main difference between the first and second example is the return type. The first return a reference and thus the object itself is not moved outside the side. The second return a value, and the object itself is returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say we have the code

```
Foo FooFactory::createFoo(int a, int b) 
{
    return Foo(a, b);  // returns an instance of Foo
}

int main() {
    Foo foo = FooFactory::createFoo(0, 0);
}
```

It is important to distinguish between the various `Foo` objects created.

Conceptually, execution proceeds as follows:

1. When the expression `Foo(a, b)` in the return statement is evaluated, a temporary object of type `Foo` is created.
2. After the expression in the return statement has been evaluated, the return value itself is initialized from that expression. This results in the creation of *another* temporary of type `Foo`.
3. The temporary created in step 1 is destroyed.
4. The temporary created in step 2 is the result of the function call expression `FooFactory::createFoo(0, 0)` in the calling function. That temporary is used to initialize the non-temporary object `foo`.
5. The temporary created in step 2 is destroyed.

In the presence of copy elision and return value optimization, it is possible for both temporaries to be elided.

Note that if the function returns by reference, then step 2 does **not** create a new object; it only creates a reference. Hence, after step 3, the object referred to does not exist anymore, and in step 4, the initialization will occur from a dangling reference.

Answer (score 2):

Because the second example returns the object by value, not by reference.

The first example returns a reference to an instance of an object, the second example returns an instance of an object.

The comments you showed even state that, explicitly.

In the first example, only a reference is returned, and the referenced object gets destroyed.

In the second example, the object itself gets returned. Which means that the object "continues to exist", in a manner of speaking, and it winds up wherever the code that calls this function puts that object.

Answer (score 0):

When you return an instance, you do not extend the lifetime of the object, so it gets destroyed at the end brace of the function and your reference now refers to nothing.

If you return a class, then that class gets copied (unless RVO applies, which is a whole different thing that works effectively the same) to *outside* the function before it is destroyed, so you now have a copy of that created object that is in perfect working order and can be used fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you are (logically) returning a copy.  Imagine if you were returning an int instead of a `Foo`:

```
int FooFactory::createInt(int a, int b) 
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Can you see that this would not be an issue?
In C++, a Foo will work for the same reason an `int` does, as long as `Foo` is movable or copyable.